Can 2 curves be orthogonal at one point but not at another
My teacher gave us a note saying :

if 2 curves intersect orthogonally at one point
then they are orthogonal at all points of intersection

I do not think that is true.
Can someone explain how it is true or prove how it is not ?

certainly not! take y=x(x-1)(x+1), the derivative at 0 is -1 so y=x is normal at 0, but evidently not at the other points of intersection (graph it).

Possibly your teacher meant circles, rather than general curves?

Draw a rectangle. Let one of the curves be three of the sides and the other curve be the remaining side.

Comment Box will not let me include "Pictures/Diagrams" like this Counter-Example :

We can make unlimited such Counter-Examples . . . .
With Wolfram Online Tool , I made this Visualization Outline using Sine-Squared Curve :

The line can be easily adjusted to make one intersection orthogonal.
There may or may not be some more intersections which are orthogonal.
Every other intersection will be non-orthogonal.
